# blend 4 and layout path

Tags: windows-phone-7, expression-blend

according to this article http://electricbeach.org/?p=653 and many others it's trivial to make a layout path.

Well I've downloaded phone 7 developer kit but when I try to convert a shape (es. circle) to layout path is impossible because command is not active.
Also pathlistbox don't exist in my blend version... you know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only use the `PathListBox` in Silverlight 4 onwards, which is available on the Mango build of Windows Phone 7. You will need to download and install the [Developer Tools for Windows Phone Mango](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/news/WPDT_7.1_Beta).

Comment: thanks :), my version is 4.0.20901.1, is the same rason why I have only 2 shape(circle and square) and no all others shape that I always see during mix10 and mix11?